# Cannot receive Rails response with Ajax

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, cordova

When I post from phonegap (with ajax, in javascript) something to my rails server, the post succeeds, but I have no response from my server, so finally it fails. I don't understand why I cannot get the response ..

For example, here is my sign up script (javascript with ajax):

```
$('#sign-up-button').click(function(e) {
        var str = $("#signUpForm").serialize();
        $(".error").remove();
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({url: "http://localhost:3000/api/users.json",
            type: "POST",
            data: str,
            success: function(result, status) {
                alert('success');
                $.mobile.changePage( "welcome.html", { transition: "slide"} );
            },
            error: function(result) {
                alert('error');
            }
    });
});
```

and my code on Ruby on rails side:

```
 # POST /users
  # POST /users.json
  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @user, status: :created }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

In firebug, I have : the message 201 Created, the user is created (I can check it), but I have no response, so the message alert('error') appears ...

Thanks a lot for your advices!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just stopped to try making it working with Firefox, and launched it in X-code.
It worked.

I was wondering if I needed to work on a server to obtain a response from a post, somebody knows if X code creates a server?

Answer (score 1):

If you are expecting an empty response such as a 201, you need to specify `dataType: 'text'` in your `$.ajax` options. What's happening right now is that jQuery is attempting to parse the response as JSON, and failing as there is no response to parse.

Comment: Thanks, but it does not change anything ...
It is strange because when I add 
puts 'function read' 
at the beginning of my rails function, it does not appear in the terminal...